# XSL transform 300M with xsltproc (out of memory)

Tags: xslt

I need to transform XML file (set PRODUCTNO to ITEM_ID for all ITEM elements). There is no newline, file content is one long line.

```
<SHOP>
<ITEM>
  <NAME>...</NAME>
  <ITEM_ID>11</ITEM_ID>
  <PRODUCTNO>22</PRODUCTNO>
  <TAG>...</TAG>
</ITEM>
....
</SHOP
```

First try was with xsltproc, but i ended with "killed" (out of memmory, consumed 2G) with 300M file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ITEM_ID">
  <ITEM_ID><xsl:value-of select = "../PRODUCTNO" /></ITEM_ID>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Well, i learn XSL today :) Is it possible to write it better (more memory efficient), or have to use another processor. I tried sed with no success, due to line by line processing.

```
sed -r -e 's///g'
```

Xsl processor would be better.

Comment: It should be possible to solve this using XSLT 3.0 and streaming with Saxon 9.7 EE but you need at least a trial license or buy a commercial license to use that product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mixture of streaming and copying you could solve it in XSLT 3.0 using

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="STREAMABLE" static="yes" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>

    <xsl:mode _streamable="{$STREAMABLE}" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:mode name="change" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="change"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM_ID" mode="change">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="../PRODUCTNO"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This processes the initial input document in a streamed mode and then creates a copy of each `ITEM` element to use normal template matching on it to transform the `ITEM_ID`.

To use XSLT 3.0 and streaming, you need to use Saxon 9.7 EE (available from http://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml) or Exselt (available from http://exselt.net/).

On the other hand 300 MB sounds doable with a normal XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor if you can grant it enough memory on today's desktop PCs.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It will run on server, in small interval, so i was looking for memory/processor eff. solution.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Martin Honnen about XSL 3.0 is correct!
Finally I used [SED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), due to the license.

My solution is:

1. put every ITEM on a single line
2. do substitution (`ITEM_ID` is always in front of `PRODUCTNO`)

So the SED solution looks like:

```
cat file.xml | sed -e 's/<ITEM>/\n<ITEM>/g' | sed -e 's/<ITEM_ID>(.*)<\/ITEM_ID>(.*)<PRODUCTNO>(.*)<\/PRODUCTNO>/<ITEM_ID>\3</ITEM_ID>\2<PRODUCTNO>\3<\/PRODUCTNO>/g'
```

It is not as safe as SLT processing, but speed/memory consumption wins.